# Heat shielding paper under radiator cover?

Tags: insulation, radiator

What am I looking at here with this paper-ish material on the underside of all my radiator covers? They are pretty old covers, but I don't believe they are as old as the house (1923).

Is this... dare I say ... asbestos?!

Also, if it is, is there a newer product for this application? (my initial googling didnt come up with much but automative radiator wraps)

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe there is a strong possibility that is asbestos.  Please get it tested and, if confirmed, professionally abated.

I believe there are some fiberglass-based products that would be a good choice today.

Comment: I'll grab a kit off amazon and have it tested then. You wouldn't by chance know of any exact brands/products for the replacements? I keep searching but come up peaches for something to use.

Comment: Search "fiberglass insulation paper" for some ideas.  Generally specific product recommendations are off-topic for Stack Exchange.

Comment: ceramic fiber insulation paper will also yield results, though most will far exceed (temperature-wise) what you require in this application.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks... I realize specific brands and urls is prolly disallowed, but thanks for helping with which search terms to utilize!

Comment: After a day of searching, I'm getting nowhere. The only thin stuff I can find is super expensive 4000° rated automotive exhaust wrappings in small quantities. There just doesnt seem to be anything out there that is roughly ~1/8-1/4" thin for this application (got 6x 5' covers and 1x 3', all 10" wide). If it turns out asbestos, I may just have to go without anything under the cover tops and deal with the tops getting super hot (~180° at times).